# Update Spring HashMap during Java runtime

Tags: java, spring

What is the best way to implement the cache to hold singleton objects that gets created dynamically during java runtime with spring DI ?

I was trying to do as in my code snippet, but it does not work.

```
Class GenericTranslator {


    @Resource
    private Map<String, LanguageTranslator> languageTranslators;


    public String translate(String input, string language){
           LanguageTranslator lt
          if(objects.containsKey(language)){
                lt = languageTranslators.get(language);
          } else{
           //LanguageTranslator creation is costly and memory consuming
             lt = initLanguageTranslator(language);
             languageTranslators.put(keyName, newObject)
          }
        return lt.translate(input);

   }
}
```

Comment: Put `@Cacheable` on the method and be finished.

Comment: Spring has a `MessageSource` concept that does this for you.

Comment: @chrylis: keeping Cacheable for the method translate will make the response cached. I need to cache the languageTranslators objects instead.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt:  MessageSource provides converting to different locals. In my use case, I need to cache the the run time reusable objects.

Comment: It seems like (1) you are reinventing localization functions that are already provided, (2) you don't so much want a _cache_ as _lazy initialization_, and (3) you're looking for `Map#computeIfAbsent`.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with @Cacheable.